# How to print multiple sentences using an array element within a string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple JavaScript function which takes a string as an input. For example, if my "place" array has the elements, "house", "farm", "barn", "hotel" and I input this string:

```
Hello, welcome to my $place. I hope you like it here at my $place.
```

The output would be this:

```
Hello, welcome to my house. I hope you like it here at my house.
Hello, welcome to my farm. I hope you like it here at my farm.
Hello, welcome to my barn. I hope you like it here at my barn.
Hello, welcome to my hotel. I hope you like it here at my hotel.
```

Comment: Where's the code you wrote? What exactly is not working about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your elements inside an array, then just iterate over it, e.g. with `Array#forEach` and log each string with specified element from the array.

```js
var place = ["house", "farm", "barn", "hotel"];
    place.forEach(v => console.log("Hello, welcome to my " + v + ". I hope you like it here at my " + v + "."));
```

If you want to display exactly what the user has entered, use following method.

```js
var place = prompt();

console.log("Hello, welcome to my " + place + ". I hope you like it here at my " + place + ".");
```

Comment: Well, seeing as SO is not a code-writing service, people ask for an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to know that the OP has actually tried something to solve the issue. When they post their code, we can then step in and help debug or fix it.

Comment: But for the record, I did not downvote the question or your answer - just letting you know why people would.

Comment: Okay thank you but is there anyway to do this without hard coding the values? I want the program to be able to accept an input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

Using some nice ES2015 features (block scope variables, template literals and arrow functions).

```js
let places = ["house", "farm", "barn", "hotel"];
places.forEach(a=>console.log(`Hello, welcome to my ${a}!`));
```

Alternatively, how about some nice generator functions?

```js
function* welcome2places(placesArray) {
  let places = placesArray;
  yield* places;
}
let welcome = welcome2places(["house", "farm", "barn", "hotel"]);
let welcomeMessage = welcome.next();
while (!welcomeMessage.done) {
   console.log(`Welcome to my ${welcomeMessage.value}!`);
   welcomeMessage = welcome.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May map each array element with the sentence, trough replacing all occurences of "$place" with the element...

```
console.log(["house","farm"].map(el=>"Hello, welcome to my $place. I hope you like it here at my $place.".split("$place").join(el)).join("\n");
```

Comment: I like that creative use of split/join!

Comment: Well, I'd rather use a template string or string concatenation for this, since it's more efficient. Array operations are quite costly...

Comment: @Christoph but it enables the user to use user input as the main string... however it might be better to cache the array, but who cares...

Comment: Caching the array does not have a real impact here. It's more the split and join operations that are rather costly. Good point in the user input though! Just out of curiosity a very simple benchmark: https://jsfiddle.net/poikl/rk3s86x5/ Template strings seem to be ~ twice as fast. I did not benchmark my generator function though :-D How do you possibly extract the keyword from the user string (without the user having to explicitly specify it)?